# Bitcoin Withdrawn from Cryptobridge not showing up on my Bitcoin Core Wallet

Tags: wallet, withdrawal

Hey so I sold my Argo on Crypto-bridge and received bitcoin. When I withdraw said Btc to my bitcoin core wallet, how long does it take for it to show up?
There are two transactions in question here:
1) I withdraw the bitcoin to my wallet when it was syncing. Now that the syncing is done, I don't see anything show up. It's been 2 days now 
2) I withdrew bitcoin to my wallet after it was done syncing. How long will this one get into my wallet. This happens today.

Both of these transactions have went through on Crypto-bridge but never showed up on my end.
My wallet address for bitcoin is

13zQ6niRwL4kWrJs76BCsf3FmERtBWDYke

Is Crypto-Bridge a scam market?

Please help me out

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You ask a good question, I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I have no information on Crypto-bridge.

Currently, no transactions seem to have been broadcast to the network for [your address](https://blockchain.info/address/13zQ6niRwL4kWrJs76BCsf3FmERtBWDYke).

You should confirm that you sent BTC to you Bitcoin Core wallet (and not altcoins with a different symbol, not BTC). I would get in touch with Crypto-bridge customer support to enquire.